# trying to check existance of parent element with attr in xml with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am trying to create a if statement that checks if a parent with a certain I.D. exists in a external xml. If it exists I want it to write it, and if it doesn't I want it to echo a default text in html. I get it to return [Object][object], but I cant get it to run the else statement if I delete the parent from the xml. Any ideas?

```
function xml() {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").append("<ul></ul>");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"xml.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(d) {
         $(d).find('parent[id="1111"]').each(function(){
                if ($(this) != undefined){
               document.write('<li<b>something</b>'
                                +$(this).find("id").text()
                               +'</li><li><b>else </b>'+
                              $this).find("Status").text()
                    +'</li>';
                }
                else{
                document.write('<li id="1104"><b>something:</b>'
                                +' 1104</br><li><b>else:</b> Down ');}

})
}
})
            });

        }

<root>
<parent id="1111">
 <child> Hello World</child
</parent>
</root>
```

The xml repeats after this, just with different ids.

Comment: please paste the xml structure as well

Comment: I suggest stepping back from your current task and reading through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour or two, and pays you back that time *immediately*. Probably also useful to walk through some jQuery tutorials.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, I've removed the `php` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You're parsing XML as though it were HTML. Instead, use [`parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/). Then your `find` should work. You don't need `each`:

```
success: function(d) {
    var elm = $($.parseXML(d).find('parent[id="1111"]'));
    if (elm[0]) {
        // Found it
    } else {
        // Didn't find it
    }
}
```

Separately, note that calling `document.write` after the main parsing of the page is complete is almost never a good idea: It **completely wipes out the page** by doing an implicit call to `document.open`. You probably wanted to use jQuery's `append`, `appendTo`, `prepend`, `prependTo`, etc.

Also, `$("div").append("<ul></ul>");` will add a `ul` to **every** `div` on the page.

Here's an example appending a list to one specific div. I call it twice, once with XML that has the element, and once with XML that doesn't:

```js
function fakeAjaxResponse(target, d) {
  var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(target);

  var elm = $($.parseXML(d)).find('parent[id="1111"]');
  if (elm[0]) {
    // Found it
    $("<li>").text("Found the element: " + elm.text()).appendTo(ul);
  } else {
    // Didn't find it
    $("<li>").text("Didn't find the element").appendTo(ul);
  }
}
fakeAjaxResponse(
  "#first-result",
  '<root><foo><parent id="1111">I'm 1111</parent></foo></root>'
);
fakeAjaxResponse(
  "#second-result",
  '<root><foo><parent id="1122">I'm 1122</parent></foo></root>'
);
```

```html
<div id="first-result"></div>
<div id="second-result"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```